# configure Apache reverse proxy to work with CKAN dataset preview

Tags: apache, docker, reverse-proxy, ckan

I tried to configure Apache's reverse proxy on a running CKAN instance; most pages work, with a few exceptions (notably data preview and user login).
What I did: I’ve set up a CKAN instance using docker, at http://my.intranetwebsite.fr:8082
I’ve deployed it into : http://cybis.univ-grenoble-alpes.fr:8082
(port 80 is already used).
Tests shows that everything worked well on port 8082.
I now want to have this web page accessible on port 80. We use apache’s reverse proxy for several services on this website, so I’ve added this to /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
<Location /data>
ProxyPass http://localhost:8082 retry=0
ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8082
SetOutputFilter proxy-html
ProxyHTMLURLMap http://localhost:8082
</Location>
RewriteRule ^/data$ /data/ [R]
```

And I've changed the parameters in production.ini:

```
ckan.root_path = /data/{{LANG}}
ckan.site_url = http://cybis.univ-grenoble-alpes.fr
```

And restarted apache on the host, and restarted the container.
Everything works fine on :80/data except the login, and a strange behaviour for the data explorer: it gets an iframe with the home page of the ckan in place of the explorer.
Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

If you use `ckan.root_path` then think you may well have to change the paths in `who.ini` too, e.g. `login_form_url = /data/user/login`.

For the Data Explorer, maybe someone else can suggest. One of his example URLs is here: http://cybis.univ-grenoble-alpes.fr/data/dataset/militarized-interstate-disputes-v4-3/resource/55ed7ecb-841b-47c0-80cd-65fa80a04401 and shows a 404 error in the iframe where the preview should be.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. It does not work, though. I did:
    `docker ps # get container id`

    `docker exec -it 1234-ContainerId /bin/bash`

    `vi /usr/lib/ckan/venv/src/ckan/ckan/config/who.ini`

    `login_form_url= /data/user/login
    login_handler_path = /data/login_generic
    logout_handler_path = /data/user/logout
    post_login_url = /data/user/logged_in
    post_logout_url = /data/user/logged_out`

Comment: The URL of the login page was correct before and after the change. After the page, the logged-in landing page became /data/data/user/...  (with 'data' twice), with same 404 error. However, before the changes in who.ini, landing page was with port 8082 (:8082/data/user/logged_in), port 80 after the change (.fr/data/data/user/logged_in). You can try with a random user and password, you should  see a 404 anyway

Comment: So who.ini may not indeed need changing then. Another idea - I see from the headers your using 'paster serve' instead of apache modwsgi. I wonder if that is somehow adding the :8082 in?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The problem is that, except for CKAN, the other services that are reverse-proxied through Apache are not Python apps, so we cannot use modwsgi for those. I'm not sure how to use modwsgi side by side with paster. In any case the offical doc says paster and a reverse proxy can be used with CKAN, see https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/maintaining/installing/deployment.html

Comment: That doc is not meant to endorse/encourage using paster for production, just saying it is possible. Maybe it's fine, but it doesn't give me confidence. We've been wanting for a long while to change the instructions to just show a modern gunicorn or uwsgi setup.

Comment: Adding  ProxyHTMLURLMap directives in apache2.conf, and rules for both "localhost" and "cybis.univ-grenoble-alpes.fr" fixed one of the issues (link to data, to download .csv files), but login page and Data explorer page are unreachable. The data page containes an ifrmae for the Data explorer which is incorrect, as it has ":8082/data/" in it; somehow it got written or rewritten badly.